# Intersection of class number one fields

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Let $F$ and $K$ be two number fields with class number one. How can one prove that the class number of $F \cap K$ is also equal to one.

I have been trying to prove something like the intersection of the hilbert class fields is the hilbert class field of the intersection but I haven't been able to do so nor  have I any kind of indication that it should be true.

Can we say something in general about the class number of the intersection of two fields ? Or about the Hilbert class field of the intersection of two fields ?

Anyway i'm guessing this assertion must have a way more elementary answer.

Comment: Certainly true for cyclotomic fields (we have $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)\cap \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{(n,m)})$).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Do you mean by just checking that for all $m,n$ such that $h_{\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)}=h_{\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)}=1$ (which is a small list) that $h_{\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{(m,n)})}=1$ (i.e that $(m,n)$ is on that list)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first (non general) question is a consequence of lemma 2.1 of the following notes : https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~osserman/classes/254a/lectures/35.pdf.

It says that if $K$ is a number field and if $L$ is an extension of $K$ with class number one then the hilbert class field $F\cap K$ is contained in $L$. Then clearly in out case the hilbert class field is contained in both $F$ and $K$ so it is equal to $F\cap K$ which implies that $F \cap K$ has class number one.

I won't accept this answer yet since i'm still looking for a more general one or maybe for a more elementary approach to the first question.

Comment: Well the existence of the hilbert class field isn't elementary at all. And maybe there is an easier way.

Comment: Yeah sure :) I mean I was just wondering. This answer is fine for me.